# Running vanilla project generated with JHipster is getting errors

Tags: jhipster

I am having problems running a sample application generated with jhipster.

I kicked off `yo jhipster` and everything worked fine with no errors through the project generation phrase. However, when I try to start the project using `gradle bootRun` or `gradle run`, the home page is not rendering correctly with a lot of javascript errors...

See http://www.screencast.com/t/hYF4ZEd0

Can you tell what could possibly be wrong? As I said, the generation phase worked fine with no errors and looking at the project structure, I can see the node_components and bower ones are there. So not sure why its not able to find angular and what not (see http://www.screencast.com/t/wW2J5CtaBa1u).

I am running the latest version of jhipster (v. 1.2.2).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I didn't have bower installed on my machine. Dah! Feeling really silly right now...
Installed it and ran `bower install` and everything is good now.

Thanks!